# delete a row from jqgrid as well as database table using jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqgrid

I am trying to delete a row from jqgrid using the below code and I am successful in doing that.But, now I have to delete the same row from database too.Can you provide me with a solution to easily do the same.I have one approach, to create a stored procedure for deleting the selected row in db and calling the SP in my js code. Any alternate solution would be appreciated. The DB table name is **SubCategoryAttribute** from where i need to delete the row.              #Thanks

```
 $scope.deleteCondition = function () {
    var selectedRowId = $("#jqConditionsGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    var selectedrowData = jQuery("#jqConditionsGrid").getRowData(selectedRowId);
    var selectedRowAttribute = selectedrowData['attributename'];
    if (selectedRowId == null) {
        alert('Please select a row to delete.');
        return;
    }
    //Delete the row
    $('#jqConditionsGrid').jqGrid('delRowData', selectedRowId);}
```

Comment: once you delete a row, make an `ajax request` to the `backend` and pass the `id` and there you can make use of the SP.. Bdw.. what backend you are using?

Comment: if you use `editurl` or `url` options or `delRowData` then jqGrid will send (post) *automatically* the del request to the server and it will delete the local row only after the server did it. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server2). Thus you need just implement the delete method in your server code where you delete the row from the database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are need to make a delete request to the back-end (code that runs on the server), using e.g. [Node.js](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm), [Spring.js](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) or [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). Example using Web API:

```
public class ConditionController : ApiController
{
  public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int rowId)
  {
    try
    {
      // Your code to delete a category from database
    }
    catch (Exception)
      {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); // Error     
      }
   }
}
```

Then from your front-end (javascript that runs in you browser) you can call the same request using Angular's [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http.delete("api/Condition/" + rowId).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```